# xcode iphone scrollview scale

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, uiscrollview, scale

What I want to do is an horizontal scroll view with buttons inside and when A button came at the center of the screen it became bigger. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intercept the delegate method for scrollViewDidScroll: and monitor the scrollviews contentOffset.  Doing so will allow you to make any adjustments each time the scrollview moves. As your button.center moves closer to your scrollviews center, increase its frame.size.  Be sure not to do anything overly complex in scrollViewDidScroll bc it will be called a lot.

Comment: I think the first step for you should be to successfully initialize a scrollView and add it to your view, set the delegate to the controller of the view you just added the scrollview.  within the method simply NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Offset x:%.2f y:%.2f", scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y] after you can see this in your console it should be clear how you can use this method to adjust the frame of a button.

Comment: ok I try this but it doesn't work I realy need a sample code .